# JQuery selector by data attribute when data is added dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` with several items. I populate the list dynamically after page load using jquery. As I add each list item, I also add an "itemID" to the data of that element using the jquery ".data()" function. Something like this:

```
var item = $('<li>My Item Name</li>');
item.data('itemID', '123ABC456');
```

Later, I need a selector to determine if there is any item in my item list with a specific itemID. First I tried using:

```
$('*[data-itemID="123ABC456"]');
```

This didn't work - and on further research, I discovered that this syntax only works if the data attribute was set in the DOM when the page was loaded; it doesn't work if you use the ".data" jquery method dynamically.

Next I tried:

```
$(':data(itemID==123ABC456)');
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. If I run simply `$(':data(itemID)')`, however, then I *do* get all the li elements that have an itemID in their data.

I know that the itemID attribute is set correctly, as when I call `.data()` on that list item I get:

```
Object { itemID="123ABC456"}
```

How can I select all elements that have an itemID of "123ABC456" in their data?

Comment: have you tried just iterating over all <li> items on a page that contain a data attribute and plucking the result you're looking for out of there?

Comment: I have made a JSfiddle. Effectivelly finding dynamic data by selector don't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/A5652/
"The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery)."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/w28p9/1/ <-- jsFiddle example showing differences with data-attribute & jquery.data()

`jQuery.data()` is different than HTML5 data-NAME attributes which you are trying to search for.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

jQuery.data() saves inside of the jquery element (this data is hidden from plain sight).
Looking for `[data-itemID]` would work if inside of the actual had: `<li data-itemID="12345"></li>`.

To retrieve and look for the actual hidden `.data()` try:

```
// of course be more specific than just searching through all <li>'s
$('li').each(function () {
    if ( $(this).data('itemID') === '123ABC456' ) {
        // do whatever you wanted to do with it
    } 
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to avoid a loop - but I guess a selector is in essence a loop anyway. This worked for me :)

Comment: You can use `filter()` function with filtering by data-attributes after `children()` or `find()` selector functions

Answer (score 9):

Instead of

```
$(item).data('itemID', '123ABC456')
```

use

```
$(item).attr('data-itemID', '123ABC456')
```

Then you can use

```
$('[data-itemID=123ABC456]')
```

as a selector

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the itemID in the DOM:

```
var item = $('<li itemID="'+itemid+">My Item Name</li>');
```

Comment: I really don't want to have custom attributes. I thought of doing this with the "rel" attribute, but using data seemed more logical. I didn't realize that there was no easy selector, though...